# Essential supremum is itself an essential upper bound?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

How can I prove that the essential supremum is itself an essential upper bound?

i.e. For an essentially bounded function, in the relation $S=\inf\{M: |f(x)| ≤ M \mbox{ a.e.}\}$, can the infimum be taken as a minimum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if $S$ is finite, then for a fixed $n$, take $N_n$ of measure $0$ such that on its complement, $|f(x)|\leq S+\frac 1n$. Then take $N:=\bigcup_{n\geq 1}N_n$. $N$ is of measure $0$, and on its complement $|f(x)|\leq S$.

But we may not have $|f(x)|<S$, for example if we take $f$ constant.

Comment: Yeah @t.b. you are right, I already changed it in the original post.

Comment: Sorry I am asking here but I don't my small question is worth asking it with the questions. Can you please notify the difference between the definition of essential supremum and essential bound? Or is it the same thing with 2 different names? @Davide Giruado