# If $T$ is measure preserving, then $f\mapsto f\circ T$ is an isometry on $L^\infty$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal E,\mu)$ be a probability space and $T:E\to E$ be $(\mathcal E,\mathcal E)$-measurable with $$T_\ast\mu=\mu\tag1.$$ How can we show that $$\mathcal L^p(\mu)\ni f\mapsto f\circ T\tag2$$ is an isometry on $\mathcal L^p(\mu)$ for all $p\in[1,\infty]$?

This is trivial, using $(1)$, when $p<\infty$. But I've no idea how we can show it when $p=\infty$. Maybe in the following: Let $f\in\mathcal L^\infty(\mu)$. Assume first that $f(E)$ is finite, i.e. $$f=\sum_{i=1}^ka_i1_{A_i}\tag3$$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$, $a_1,\ldots,a_k\in\mathbb R$ and disjoint $A_1,\ldots,A_k\in\mathcal E$. Then $$f\circ T=\sum_{i=1}^ka_i1_{A_i}\tag4.$$ If the sets $A_i$ would be $T$-invariant (i.e. $1_{A_i}\circ T=1_{A_i}$) we could conclude $f\circ T=f$. But this would mean that $f$ is measurable wrt the $\sigma$-algebra of $T$-invariant sets ...

However, if we could prove the claim in the case where $f(E)$ is finite, we could easily conclude by denseness of the elementary functions in $L^\infty(\mu)$.

Comment: "This is trivial, using $(1)$, when $p<\infty$": do write the proof and check that (besides not being trivial) gives you automatically also the case when $p=\infty$. Otherwise look at the points with infinite values for a representative of a function in $\mathcal L^\infty(\mu)$.

Comment: @JohnB The argument in the case $p< \infty$ should be that $\int |f|^p d\mu = \int |f|^p dT_* \mu = \int |f \circ T|^p d \mu$ where the first equality is by the measure preserving nature of $T$ and the second is a standard result. This really does seem trivial and doesn't seem to me to work at all in the case $p = \infty$ and so you do need a new argument there. Is there something I've missed?

Comment: That "standard result" of yours is not trivial. Can you provide even a single reference? Yes, instead of integrating take the supremum and apply the "standard result".

Comment: @JohnB See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331950/pushforward-measure-integral-property/331958) for a proof of that result which is really just an easy application of the standard machine. The proof of the result I link to doesn't work at all though if you replace the integral with an essential supremum.

Comment: Good, now you proceed in the same way for $p=\infty$ (but since you already have an answer, precisely as I suggested, I leave it now).

Comment: @JohnB Notice that I didn't post the question, I posted the answer before commenting in response to you. But that answer is not at all "precisely as you suggested". The proof I give in the answer is entirely different to the proof of the "standard result" since you aren't able to utilize the standard machine and have to exhibit suitable null sets to get inequalities instead.

Comment: @RhysSteele Yes it is exactly as I suggested, sorry for not engaging in the discussion.

Comment: @JohnB I wrote that it is trivial, since I've got the standard result about the integration wrt pushforward measures mentioned by Rhys Steele in mind.

Comment: Great, as I said in the beginning then. When we assume something we can prove more. It was good that I could be of help in solving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I will show that for any $f \in L^\infty(\mu)$, we have that $\|f\|_\infty \leq \|f \circ T\|_\infty$.

For this, take a null set $A$ such that $\|f \circ T\|_\infty = \sup_{\Omega \setminus A} |f \circ T|$. Then $$\mu[T(\Omega \setminus A)] = \mu[T^{-1}(T(\Omega \setminus A))] \geq \mu(\Omega \setminus A) = 1$$ so that $\mu[T(\Omega \setminus A)] = 1$. As a result, we have that $$\|f\|_\infty \leq \sup_{T(\Omega \setminus A)} |f| = \sup_{\Omega \setminus A} |f \circ T| = \|f \circ T\|_\infty.$$

For the other inequality, take a null set $B$ such that $\|f\|_\infty = \sup_{\Omega \setminus B} |f|$. We would like to say that 
$$\sup_{\Omega \setminus B} |f| = \sup_{T^{-1}(\Omega \setminus B)} |f \circ T| $$ so that we could immediately conclude using the fact that $\|f \circ T\|_\infty \leq \sup_{T^{-1}(\Omega \setminus B)} |f \circ T|$. Unfortunately, since $T$ need not be surjective, $TT^{-1}(\Omega \setminus A) = (\Omega \setminus A) \cap T(\Omega)$ may be strictly smaller than $\Omega \setminus A$. The saving grace is that the difference is a measure $0$ set.

Indeed, by a similar argument as given earlier, $\mu[T(\Omega)] = 1$, so we must have that 
$$\sup_{\Omega \setminus B} |f| = \sup_{(\Omega \setminus B) \cap T(\Omega)} |f|$$
since otherwise $B \cup T(\Omega)^c$ is a null set such that $\|f\|_\infty > \sup_{\Omega \setminus(B \cup T(\Omega)^c)} |f|$ which contradicts the definition of $\|f\|_\infty$. We have that $$\mu(T^{-1}((\Omega \setminus B) \cap T(\Omega))) = \mu((\Omega \setminus B) \cap T(\Omega)) = 1$$
This implies that 
$$\|f \circ T\|_\infty \leq \sup_{T^{-1}((\Omega \setminus B) \cap T(\Omega))} |f \circ T| = \sup_{(\Omega \setminus B) \cap T(\Omega)} |f| = \sup_{\Omega \setminus B} |f| = \|f\|_\infty$$
which completes the proof.

Comment: Why do the null sets $A$ and $B$ exist?

Comment: This follows from the definition of the essential supremum and a very short argument. See the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126883/essential-supremum-is-itself-an-essential-upper-bound) for that argument. This is a useful characterisation of the norm of an $f \in L^\infty$ to keep in mind.

Comment: How did you get the first inequality $\|f\|_\infty \leq \sup_{T(\Omega \setminus A)} |f|$? Actually, shouldn't it be the other way around, $\sup_{T(\Omega \setminus A)} |f|\le \|f\|_\infty$?

Comment: No, recall the definition of the essential supremum (in particular the infimum over null sets taken in it). The complement of $T(\Omega\setminus A)$ is a null set.

Comment: Wait a second, what are you denoting by $\left\|f\right\|_\infty$? I use this notation for the actual supremum of a function $f$, but I guess you're using for the norm on $L^\infty$, right?

Comment: Yes I mean the $L^\infty$ norm. I thought this would be obvious since otherwise the entire answer is meaningless. For example, the supremum isn't well-defined on $L^\infty$ since e.g. there is $f \in L^\infty$ such that $f = 0$ a.e. but $\sup f = \infty$. Even if we ignore that issue, if $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ denoted the supremum (not essential supremum) this answer wouldn't prove that $f \mapsto f \circ T$ is an isometry since we'd never even involve the actual norm on $L^\infty$. Note also that I explicitly refer to using the essential supremum in my comment from April 26th.

Comment: I don't get why $\mu[T(\Omega \setminus A)] = 1$.

Comment: I edited to explain that (and also to add a bit of motivation for the proof of the other inequality since on rereading I felt that what I wrote for that introduced a set out of nowhere). Hopefully, this makes things clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit!